# nav-tabs with dropdown-menu in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a sample using bootstrap. My issue is nav-tabs in which I want to have working dropdown menu and switch between. Here is my nav-tabs with names:| City 1 | Citys 2 | City 3 / Each of the cities has its own content. Lets say City 2 has a drop down menu. When press on it shows two addresses for choice. If you choose any address it shows its own content.
Here is my HTML:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#City1" data-toggle="tab">City1</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#City2">City2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#Address1">Address1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Address2">Address2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#City3" data-toggle="tab">City3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="City1">
        <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></h4>Lorem profile dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
        <p>Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis dolor, in sagittis nisi.</p>
              </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Address1">
        <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></h4>Lorem profile dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
        <p>Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis dolor, in sagittis nisi.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="Address2">
        <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></h4>Lorem profile dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
                <p>Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis dolor, in sagittis nisi.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="City3">
        <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></h4>Lorem settings dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
        <p>Quisque mauris augue, molestie.</p>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Tabs do work with the dropdown: http://www.bootply.com/122756 What's not working for you?

Comment: Thank you Skelly, Isherwood helped me with this isssue. I missed data-toggle attribute in my address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `data-toggle` attribute on the links in the dropdown.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/224eT

```
<li><a href="#Address1" data-toggle="tab">Address1</a></li>
<li><a href="#Address2" data-toggle="tab">Address2</a></li>
```